# break or continue jump across class boundary kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

is anyone facing this problem.

`break or continue jump across class boundary kotlin`

this problem appears when i am going to use break or continue. inside lambda with receiver i create 'letIn'

lambda with receiver code

```
fun letIn(componentName: String?, values: List<LifeService.Value?>?,
       body: (String, List<LifeService.Value?>) -> Unit) {
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(componentName) && (values != null && values.isNotEmpty())) {
     body(componentName!!, values)
  } 
}
```

this sample code for it.

```
for (option in 0 until optionsSize) {
    val component = optionsGroup?.options?.get(option)
    component?.let {
        with(component) {
            letIn(presentation, values, { componentName, values ->
                if (componentName == LifeComponentViewType.CHECKBOX) {
                    letIn(transformCheckBoxValues(optionsGroup), { data ->
                        dataSource?.push(componentName, ComponentDataCheckBoxCollection(name, data))
                        view.buildComponent(componentName)
                         // break or continue didnt work
                    })
                } else {
                    dataSource?.push(componentName, ComponentDataCollection(name, values))
                    view.buildComponent(componentName)
                }
            })
        }
    }
 }
```

because above code didnt work so i use imperative way.

```
for (option in 0 until optionsSize) {
val component = optionsGroup?.options?.get(option)
        if (component != null) {
            val presentation: String? = component.presentation
            val values = component.values
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(presentation)) {
                if (presentation == LifeComponentViewType.CHECKBOX) {
                    val data = transformCheckBoxValues(optionsGroup)
                    if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
                        dataSource?.push(presentation, ComponentDataCheckBoxCollection(optionsGroup.name, data))
                        view.buildComponent(presentation)
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    dataSource?.push(presentation!!, ComponentDataCollection(component.name, values))
                    view.buildComponent(presentation!!)
                }
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

does anyone have suggestions?

**UPDATE**
i've been fix this issue by inlining high order function.

Comment: First example, second `letIn` only has two parameters, but is defined to take 3.

Comment: this lambda with receiver in kotlin.

Comment: Neither your lambda, nor your function taking the lambda have a receiver.  See [Function Literal with Reeivers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)

Comment: See my updated answer where I show you how to declare a function (and a lambda) to take a receiver.

Comment: Hi, sure. i will try it and info to you soon. thanks for helping me

Comment: See also [Why can't use continue in let or run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182565/why-cant-use-continue-in-let-or-run) for a workaround answer and a good forecast in [KT-1436](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1436).

Answer (score 17):

(Other coding errors aside) You are seeing the error because inside your lambda, you cannot use `break` or `continue` to jump out of the lambda to the nearest loop. Instead, you can use a qualified `return` to jump out of the lambda to a label.

Referring to [the language reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#returns-and-jumps)

> The return-expression returns from the nearest **enclosing function**, i.e. foo. (Note that such non-local returns are supported only for lambda expressions passed to inline functions.) If we need to return from a lambda expression, we have to **label it and qualify the return**:

(Emphasis mine)

Your second example shows that you want your lambdas to do a non-local return from the enclosing function.  Therefore, you do not need to qualify your `return`, but your function `letIn` must be declared `inline` (else you can only do a local, qualified return).

```
inline fun letIn(componentName: String?, values: List<LifeService.Value?>?,
       body: (String, List<LifeService.Value?>) -> Unit) {
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(componentName) && (values != null && values.isNotEmpty())) {
     body(componentName!!, values)
  } 
}
```

... or if you want it to have receivers...

```
inline fun String?.letIn(values: List<LifeService.Value?>?,
                         body: String.(List<LifeService.Value?>) -> Unit) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(this) && (values != null && values.isNotEmpty())) {
        this!!.body(values)
    }
}
```

When you declare `letIn` as `inline`, then you can place `return` in your lambdas without the compiler complaining. Your function would not need to be `inline` if your lambdas are only doing local returns, but it would need to have a qualified return (for example `return@letIn`).

Your first example would then look like this...

```
for (option in 0 until optionsSize) {
    val component = optionsGroup?.options?.get(option)
    component?.let {
        with(component) {
            presentation.letIn(values, { values ->
                if (this == LifeComponentViewType.CHECKBOX) {
                    this.letIn(transformCheckBoxValues(optionsGroup), { data ->
                        dataSource?.push(this, ComponentDataCheckBoxCollection(this, data))
                        view.buildComponent(this)
                        return //returns from function
                    })
                } else {
                    dataSource?.push(this, ComponentDataCollection(name, values))
                    view.buildComponent(this)
                    return  //returns from function
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, note that if you wanted to jump out of the lambda early, but continue an outer loop as in:

```
fun test1() {
    val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")
    val optionsSize = 2
    for(i in 0..optionsSize) loop@ {
        println("calliing list.forEach")
        list.forEach lit@ {
            if(it == "a") return@lit
            if(it == "c") return@loop
            println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

It won't work.  Intelli-sense doesn't complain about it, but the compiler throws an internal error.  But you can convert the outer loop to a lambda, and it does work...

```
fun test() {
    val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")
    val optionsSize = 2
    (0..optionsSize).forEach() loop@ {
        println("calliing list.forEach")
        list.forEach lit@ {
            if(it == "a") return@lit
            if(it == "c") return@loop
            println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this only works if the function to which the lambda is passed is declared `inline` (like `forEach` is declared `inline`).