# Why can't use continue in let or run

Tags: kotlin

Why it is not allowed to `continue` from `let` function?

[This code](https://pl.kotl.in/rWwLL82Yt):

```
fun foo(elements: List<String?>) {
    for (element in elements) {
        element?.let {
            continue  // error: 'break' or 'continue' jumps across a function or a class boundary
        }
    }
}
```

And even [this code](https://pl.kotl.in/us8P5q99P):

```
fun foo(elements: List<String?>) {
    loop@ for (element in elements) {
        element?.let {
            continue@loop  // error: 'break' or 'continue' jumps across a function or a class boundary
        }
    }
}
```

Does not compile with error:

> 'break' or 'continue' jumps across a function or a class boundary

---

I know that in this *particular* case I can use `filterNotNull` or manual check with smart cast, but my question is **why** it is not allowed to use `continue` here?

---

**Please vote for this feature here**: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1436

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These would be called "non-local" breaks and continues. According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns):

> `break` and `continue` are not yet available in inlined lambdas, but we are planning to support them too.

Using a bare (e.g. non-local) `return` inside a lambda is only supported if it is an inlined lambda (because otherwise it doesn't have awareness of the context it is called from). So `break` and `continue` should be able to be supported. I don't know the reason for the functionality to be delayed.

Note, there are work-arounds for both of them by `run` either inside or outside the loop, and taking advantage of the fact that at least non-local returns are supported for inline functions.

```
fun foo(elements: List<String?>) {
    run {
        for (element in elements) {
            element?.let {
                println("Non-null value found in list.")
                return@run // breaks the loop
            }
        }
    }
    println("Finished checking list")
}

fun bar(elements: List<String?>) {
    for (element in elements) {
        run {
            element?.let {
                return@run // continues the loop
            }
            println("Element is a null value.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I found corresponding ticket in YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1436

Comment: So it seems the main hold-up is resolving whether you should be able to use a bare `break` or `continue` as a local break/continue from a function like `forEach`, and they're wary of committing one way or another. IMO, they should just follow the requirements for local and non-local `return`s, and maybe use a compiler warning for doing a bare break with no `@` label, since that's ambiguous in nested iteratations.